# Static marker on MapView

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, annotations

I would like to pin the marker at center in order to disable marker movement doing map drag events. When some place moves under marker I want to get the `Lat`, `Lon` and display the address of that place in the  Search bar

[image]

Comment: put this on the window at the center.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way you can do that is put arbitrary `UIView` on top of `MapView`, and make it looks like usual marker with disabled user interaction. In that case it will not move during drag events and you will retrieve map center coordinate every time. Not that it is not very efficient to do that too frequent, consider some delay, i.e. wait until user stop drag the map and then do the request